# How does current flow between two adjacent corners of a thin plate when voltage is applied?

Tags: electric-current

[image]

If it was an infinite plate then current would have radial symmetry both at A and B.

This is a finite plate I'm vehemently against the idea of current having radial symmetry because that will lead to charge accumulation as the current exiting and entering a point is not the same easily observable at C or D.

Comment: does this plate offer resistance? Otherwise the voltmeter won't show deflection

Comment: @user8718165 Yes, conductivity $\sigma$

Comment: Did you get the answer to this question? Because I'm also stuck here.

Comment: @Natsha This question was initially asked by eshamanideep on chat he doesn't know the correct answer John Rennie says assuming radial symmetry for the current distribution works https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/54160?m=49297847#49297847